# Retrofit Response , custom response fields

Tags: android, json, api, gson, retrofit

I am using Retrofit and GSON to make an API call,

the problem that I have some fields in my models that doesn't exist in the response and I need to set them manually, example:

I have in my model: fieldOne, fieldTow, fieldThree

so fieldOne, fieldTow come in the response,

but fieldThree I need to set it manually and it's depends to fieldOne, fieldTow

ex

```
if (fieldOne!= null && fieldTow!= null) {
fieldThree = true
}
```

I need to do that at the moment when create that object and parse it

can you give me some help thanks

Comment: Post your json response.

Comment: What's the issue with your current implementation? It seems fine to me.

Comment: You can create a method your model like that. `boolean isFieldThree(){ return fieldOne!= null && fieldTow!= null;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can check key exist or not using `jsonObject.has` like following way,

```
 JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
    if(jsonObject.has("reviewer_details")){
      //do process with data
    }
```

Hope this will help

Comment: I think he has a different issue.

Comment: I think he just want to check whether the key is present or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think there two ways to achive it.

1(hardest). Write own JSON typed adapter implementation and do something like @Saneesh says.
[See tutorial](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/)

2(easiest). Do this logic in getter method for your POJO object.

```
public boolean isFieldThree() {
    if (fieldthree != null) return fieldThree;
    //otherwise
    return fieldOne!= null && fieldTow!= null;
}
```